# Is there a way to go back up the fallback ladder of intents?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am creating a bot that asks questions like, "What kind of cake do you like?" and then asks for confirmation, like "You picked Chocolate Cake. Is that Correct?". How do I make it go back to asking the original question if they answer no?

I have attempted to link fallback intents by using events, but I can't find an event that triggers going back.

I want it to, if you say no, re-ask the question.

Comment: using `contexts`

Answer (score 0):

You can define "no" as a training phrase and use context on original question.

`"What kind of cake do you like?"` intent gets `isCorrect` as input context and `"You picked Chocolate Cake. Is that Correct?"` intent uses `isCorrect` as output context.

Make sure you added `isCorrect` as output in intent before `"What kind of cake do you like?".`

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [`actions.intent.CONFIRMATION`](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#confirmation) helper for these kinds of scenarios. If the user doesn't confirm the selection you would simply pose the original question again.